# What damage can a website do?

Tags: security, web

Now and then I (accidentally) come across websites that my anti-virus warns me about. Out of curiosity, what kind of damage can a website do?

I've been working in web development for around 4 years now and can't think of any 'genuine' damage worth warning the user about. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but surely browsers and basic security measures implemented by main operating systems prevent anything particularly invasive going on?

I'm talking about threats aside from anything deceptive by the way (phishing etc.). Could taxing the browser enough warrant an anti-virus warning (i.e. overload a page with resource-draining javascript)? Typically, cookies, caches and localstorage all have limits - so I can't think of what could go on there.

I suspect this may be slightly off-topic, as it's less technically specific than what I'd usually ask. I'll happily delete it if this is the case.

Comment: Given that the average user will click any button they see in order to dismiss a dialog and look at a dancing teddy bear, it's prudent to show warnings.  The website may need the user's permission to do malicious things due to browser security measures, but users are more than happy to grant that permission.

Comment: I thought this may be the case. So the answer (essentially) is 'none, without permission', but security software is protecting the users from their own naivety?

Comment: Stop at any big-box computer store like BestBuy and ask their support people what kind of stuff they're removing from the machines of all those unsuspecting hordes of average users who don't know how to do anything but click "OK" or "Install" or "Show me the kitten" or "Yes, make my machine faster". Or read the FBI warnings about the systems that have been hijacked for ransom by malware delivered to users who blindly open attachments, click links, or download files.

Comment: For the most part, yes.  There exists a non-zero chance that a website *could* make malicious use of a vulnerability in a web browser or host system, and one should never forget that.  But the vast majority of things a website could do would require at least *some* permission granted by the user.  (Aside from being really annoying with popups and such.)

Comment: It's not just naïvety. Even well-versed web professionals just don't have time to vet every site, and source. Worse, many organizations, even technical ones, use internal self-signed certificates without a properly configured CA, so users become inured to warnings and bypassing protections. You chase those people down and ask them to fix it. Months pass. Do you A) quit your job B) Constantly pester people in different parts of the org forever or C) start ignoring warnings so you can get stuff done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main risk is encountering a [drive-by download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download).

A drive-by download isn't necessarily a file download in the usual sense, it could be a browser exploit that allows executable code to download and execute on your system (known as the payload).

One example is the [Microsoft Internet Explorer colspan Element Processing Arbitrary Code Execution Vulnerability](http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewAlert.x?alertId=26057):

> Microsoft Internet Explorer contains a vulnerability that could allow
> an unauthenticated, remote attacker to execute arbitrary code on a
> targeted system.
>
> The vulnerability is due to improper processing of elements in web
> pages. An unauthenticated, remote attacker could exploit this
> vulnerability by convincing a user to view a malicious website. If
> successful, the attacker could exploit this vulnerability to execute
> arbitrary code on the system with the privileges of the user.
>
> The vulnerability is due to improper handling of constantly changed
> colspan in a fixed table layout. If colspan could be increased after
> initialization, it could trigger a heap-based buffer overflow.

However, more recent exploits exist [such as this](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-0318) one this year (2015) in Flash Player:

> Adobe Flash Player before 13.0.0.269 and 14.x through 16.x before
> 16.0.0.305 on Windows and OS X and before 11.2.202.442 on Linux allows attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a denial of service
> (memory corruption) via unspecified vectors

Another attack vector from a website could be exploitation of a cross domain attack such as [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). Such a malicious site could be making background requests to other sites you're logged into. For example, it might be making AJAX requests to `https://facebook.com/delete_account` (made up URL path), and as you're logged into Facebook your browser will pass cookies and the action would be triggered. That is, if Facebook did not have CSRF protection for the delete account function (I'm pretty sure it does though).

Another example of a cross domain attack is that the site may be trying to exploit any [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) flaw on another site you use. It could redirect you another site and capture your credentials as you log in, or it could do something more sneaky like request a site in the background and grab your session cookie. This requires the target site to contain such an XSS flaw however.

Comment: Very interesting! I don't understand how a buffer overflow from processing DOM elements could open up a system for executing code though!? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well the browser is just software. It is just as susceptible to buffer overflows as other pieces of software. That version of IE must not do bounds checking when storing the value of `colspan` - put enough data in there them, boom!, you can overflow and redirect program flow to your payload and take control of the machine.

Comment: It's the 'redirect' bit I'm struggling to get my head around. Is this all still within the context of a webpage doing the damage? i.e. could the taking control of the system be done purely from the poor way in which IE handles `colspan`? Or must something else reside on the victim's machine to take advantage of the buffer overflow?

Comment: The poor way in which IE handled `colspan`.

Comment: Still confused, not sure how script or something else in the DOM could take advantage of an incapacitated browser it's rendered in. Either way, you've more than answered my question, and if I ask anything any more specific it'll probably come over as suspicious so I'm happy with that for now. Thanks again mate, much appreciated.

Comment: Here's a [video demonstration](https://youtu.be/6AObivH47r4) (not by me). I think it takes him to the third go to make it work. All the attacker using the command line has to do is enter `shell` and he would have a Windows command prompt. Check out [this for a primer on home buffer overflows work](http://www.securitytube.net/video/1752).

Answer (score 0):

One of the main issues is that when you go onto a website it can automatically download something onto your computer. Normally an ordinary website will ask you if you are sure that you want to download the item, but a website can download something without your permission. And if the file that was downloaded was a virus, then you now have a virus on your computer and the virus can inflict any sort of damage to the computer.

See here (https://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/virus-whatis.aspx) to see the issues of a virus and how to remove them.

Comment: Although this was the kind of info I was after, I'm not sure this is the case. Surely it would have to be an executable and somehow self-execute?

Comment: It may be a technicality, but when you go to a website it not only _can_ automatically download something onto your computer, but _must_. That is the _only_ way the web works. Downloading HTML and resources, and parsing and _executing_ those resources.

Comment: I appreciate a response is, more often than not, a set of files I'll download and have rendered or displayed (obviously from a local drive), but only within the browser - surely that is bound to certain limits? Surely a website can't push a virus onto my drive?

Comment: @JayMee that's the way all viruses work, if they weren't capable of executing on their own, then nobody would ever have problems on their computers. Browsers can push viruses onto a computer. The best thing is if you can use a self-contained browser that is in a secure sandbox environment that will not allow anything to leave this environment. The problem with this is that you would lose a lot of the functionality that a browser needs

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum - I may be wrong, but I don't believe an executable can invoke itself? A change in a registry entry or OS startup config could, but it can't execute just by existing on my drive. If so, all of the comments on the OP are incorrect.

Comment: @JayMee you're right that a virus can't self-execute, but sometimes downloaded files automatically open when they finish downloading and it could be then that the virus does the damage

Comment: Yes your browser will prevent most issues, it is quite often the 3rd party software now that causes a concern. I've seen silverlight execute a file in the users computer. While this was not for malicious reasons the potential is there in any 3rd party browser add-on. And why Flash had such a bad reputation in the past for viruses.